# Get name and values of enumerator from ReflectionOnlyGetType - operation invalid in ReflectionOnlyContext

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I need to be able to enumerate through values of an enumerator in a separate assembly for which I only have the assembly qualified name.

I am able to determine the assembly qualified name, but I can't resolve the

> 'The requested operation is invalid in the ReflectionOnly context.'

when I try to enumerate it.

My main code, in assembly DevExample:

```
using System;
using ClassLibrary;

namespace DevExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            Type myEnumType = MyEnum.One.GetType();

            WriteToConsole(myEnumType);

            Type myEnumType_null = Type.GetType(myEnumType.FullName); // will return null

            string assemblyName = myEnumType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
            // assemblyName will be "ClassLibrary.MyEnum, ClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

            Type myEnumTypeFromReflection = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(assemblyName, true, false); // Will get type succesfully

            WriteToConsole(myEnumTypeFromReflection);
        }

        private static void WriteToConsole(Type enumType)
        {
            foreach (int val in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {0}", Enum.GetName(enumType, val));
            }
        }
    }
}


Then in another assembly (ClassLibrary.dll) I just defined a simple enumerator

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Zero = 0,
        One = 1,
        Two = 2
    };
}
```

On the second write to console, I get:

**The requested operation is invalid in the ReflectionOnly context.**

I need to do this to validate an .xml that defines which enumerators a particular piece of hardware is using.

Previous code has just loaded a dictionary with the name and types manually, but given that the .xml file is able to contain the assembly qualified name, it should be able to do this dynamically.

Comment: Then don't call `ReflectionOnlyGetType()` (because that'll load the assembly again but in a reflection-only context), but fully load the type for execution?

Comment: Thanks, was being stupid! Resolved it now.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't see the wood for the trees:

```
string assemblyString = @"ClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
string name = @"ClassLibrary.MyEnum";

Type myEnumTypeDynamic = Assembly.Load(assemblyString).GetType(name);
```